# Why do I keep getting - Floating point exception (core dumped) - error message?

Tags: c, variables, math, cs50

I am trying to do an incremental division (long d) on a credit card number (long cc) by 10 but I keep receiving this error message.

Floating point exception (core dumped)

`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

// testing calculation
int main(void)
{
    // variables
    long cc = get_int("CC:\n");
    long i;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        long n = pow(10,i);
        do
        {
            long d = cc/n;
            i++;
            printf("%i\n",a);

        }
        while (i < 4);
    }
}
```

`

I've tried switching doing the following, switching the data type on the variables. I've also tried changing the equation (for long d)to the below.

```
long decimal = cc/(10 * i);
```

OR

```
 for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        long n = pow(10,i);
        do
        {
            long d = (cc/n);
            i++;
            printf("%li\n",a);
        }
        while (i < 4);
```

OR

```
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        long n = 10 * i;
        do
        {
            long d = cc/n;
            i++;
            printf("%f\n",a);

        }
        while (i < 4);
```

This has the opposite effect and for whatever reason my decimal variable keeps getting interpreted as 0 instead of the equation I'm writing. Otherwise, it's listing the credit card number the same amount of time as the for loop.

Comment: What is `a` in the code?

Comment: The arguments to `pow` should be of type `double`.  You are passing `int`.

Comment: Passing `int`s to `pow()` is not inherently wrong.  They will be automatically converted to `double` (and in that sense, the arguments *are* of type `double`).  The reverse applies to the return value of `pow()`, but this is more problematic because floating-point math is inexact.  The conversion of the returned `double` to a `long` involves **truncating** the fractional part, which could and would do something like converting `0.999999999999998` to `0`.

Comment: Don't use floating-point math where integer math will do.  Don't use `pow()` for small integer powers in any case -- just multiply (or divide) instead.

Comment: Also, modifying `i` inside a `for (i = ...)` loop is either an outright mistake or a bad way to write code.

Comment: Can you make this a [mcve]?  Preferably without the non-standard `cs50.h` header which most people won't have.  Right now it doesn't compile due to the undeclared variable `a`.

Comment: Your nested loops are strange. You have a `for` loop with loop control variable `i`, and inside this a `do`...`while` loop which uses and increments the same variable. When the inner loop exits from `while (i < 4);`, the outer loop will also not repeat, so the outer loop is useless, it only initializes `i = 0`.

Comment: I'm not an expert on `cs50.h` and I don't remember where it is, but if you're reading into a `long`, you probably want something like `get_long()`.  But trying to manipulate credit card numbers as integers is endlessly problematical, as legions of CS50 students have discovered before you.  Depending on your platform, `long` might not be big enough, either, and you might need `long long`.  But the general recommendation is to use a string instead (that is, not to try to use any size of integer).

Comment: **Yours is probably a false trail anyway.** Credit card "numbers" are sequences of decimal digits, but they are not well characterized as numbers in a mathematical or computational sense.  For example, leading `0` digits are significant in credit card numbers.  I urge you to store your input in an array of `char` and work with it that way.